# What is the logic of the expression "冗談じゃない"?

Tags: expressions

Literally, 冗談じゃない means "it is not a joke" but actually it seems that the meaning of this is "something unthinkable even for a joke"( japanese definition:冗談にもそんなことを言ったりするな。).

「道楽に働いているんだろうだって? 冗談じゃない.」

"I'm working for the fun of it? Nothing of the sort!"

「冗談じゃない、この暑い中に誰かと結婚するなんて！」

"Imagine marrying anybody in this heat!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the examples you provided, your interpretation is correct:

> but actually it seems that the meaning is "something unthinkable even for a joke"

In these cases, here are some additional expressions to capture the nuance

- I'm not even joking.
- Seriously.
- Not even playing.

For this example:

> 「道楽に働いているんだろうだって? 冗談じゃない.」

I interpret this as "You think I'm working just for fun? Please!" (not as in "pretty please")

For this example:

> 「冗談じゃない、この暑い中に誰かと結婚するなんて！」

I interpret this as "I'm not even halfway joking, who would seriously get married to anyone in this heat!?"